# this.props.logged in is not a function is undefined

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

From one of tab of Tabbar while pressing Logout i added this function to navigate to login screen :

```
 logout() {
    AuthenticationService.logout();
      const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          actions: [
              NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login'})],
              key : null
      })
      this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
  }
```

It works succcessfully but when i again click Login button from Login screen it gives warning :Here is screenshots -

[image]

Could you please suggest me whats wrong i am doing here ?

Here is Logout method :

```
  async logout() {
        try {
            await authService.signOut()
            console.log("User successfully logged out")
            return true
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Log out failure", err)
            Alert.alert("Logout failed", "Try again")
            return false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with the code you are posting, I assume the problem is related to your login, api might be failing. You can add proper error handling in your login action/reducer and don't forget to set loggedIn state to false when logout is successful assuming you are using redux.

Comment: its strange how it behave some time , updated my code for logout functionality , kindly check is there any thing i need to check it here .